# Hangman loop issue

Tags: java

I have been asked to create a hangman game. I am having a problem. when i ask the user if they would like to play again the user will enter Y but the game wont restart the correct way as it wont pick a new word  and just goes on to asking to guess the letter and when the letter is enter it then stops the game and asks the user if he wants to play again. Could someone please tell me how to loop my program so that the user can play the game again.
package hangman.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
    String s = null;
    InputStream input = null;
    int play = 0;
    Path file = Paths.get("H:\\Varsity work\\Java                        
         Programming\\Programs\\HangMan\\src\\hangman\\HangMan.txt");
        input = Files.newInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new                                                      InputStreamReader(input));
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(s);
        }
        String[] linesArray = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
        String[] randomWord = new String[1];
        while (play == 0) {
            System.err.printf("Welcome to hangman.\n");
            randomWord[0] = linesArray[random];
            System.out.println(randomWord[0]);
            Random ran = new Random();
            String word = randomWord[ran.nextInt(randomWord.length)];
            char[] CharArr = word.toCharArray();
            char[] dash = word.toCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < dash.length; i++) {
                    dash[i] = '-';
                    System.out.print(dash[i]);
                }
            for (int i = 1; i <= dash.length; i++) {
                System.out.printf("\nGuess a Letter:");
                char userLetter = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

                for (int j = 0; j < CharArr.length; j++) {
                    if (userLetter == dash[j]) {
                        System.out.println("this word already exist");
                    } else if (userLetter == CharArr[j]) {
                        dash[j] = userLetter;
                        i--;
                    }
                }
                System.out.print(dash);
                if (word.equals(new String(dash))) {
                    System.out.println("\nYou have guessed the word correctly!");
                    System.out.println("Play adian? (y/n)");
                    String name = keyboard.next();
                    if(name.equals("y")) {
                        play = 0;
                    } else if(name.equals("n")) {
                        play = 1;
                        return;
                    }
                 }                
            }    
        }
    }
```

Comment: please intend your code, it´s horrible to read.

Comment: use `infite` loop with `boolean`

Comment: @HelloWorld It dosent seem to work

Comment: or you can use like `if(input.equals(Y) play(); else System.exit(0);`

Comment: sadly its not recommended but it works ;)

Comment: @HelloWorld It restarts the program but skips picking a word and asks for the user to guess a letter

Comment: The program should be structured as suggested by user @xenteros. Also you need to take care of the negative scenarios. 
But if you want to tidy up what you have, follow the below. 
Move this line inside the while loop - int random = (int) (Math.random() * 5);

Also name the while loop like outer:while

and  then the user wants to play again - continue outer;

Comment: @user3138997 still, when you agree with the answer, upvote it - I put some effort to write this architecture, it's useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current logic it's impossible because your code is to messy. You have to divide the code into methods. I would divide it into methods the following way:

```
setUpGame();
game();
cleanUpAfterGame();

setUpGame() {
    chooseWord();
    paintBasicHangman();
}

game() {
    while (alive) {
        readLetterFromUser();
        if (missedLetter) {
            paintNextPartOfHangman();
        } else {
            redraw();
            if (won()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

controller() {
    do {
        setUpGame();
        game();
        cleanUpAfterTheGame(); //optional
        wantsNewGame?();
    } while (userWantsToPlay)
```